# Проблема с загрузкой изображения

Tags: изображения, php, upload

Всем привет, прошу помочь, часа 2 не могу разобраться в чём проблема, что только не перепробовал. Вот ошибки:

```
 Warning: imagecreatefrompng(23.png) [function.imagecreatefrompng]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Z:\home\localhost\www\core\module\upload_process.php on line 13

Warning: imagesx() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in Z:\home\localhost\www\core\module\upload_process.php on line 16

Warning: imagesy() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in Z:\home\localhost\www\core\module\upload_process.php on line 17

Warning: Division by zero in Z:\home\localhost\www\core\module\upload_process.php on line 20

Warning: imagecreatetruecolor() [function.imagecreatetruecolor]: Invalid image dimensions in Z:\home\localhost\www\core\module\upload_process.php on line 22

Warning: imagecopyresized() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in Z:\home\localhost\www\core\module\upload_process.php on line 24

Warning: mkdir() [function.mkdir]: Invalid argument in Z:\home\localhost\www\core\module\upload_process.php on line 27
```

Comment: Код в студию. Явно же намекает, что 23.png - No such file or directory in...
Да и Invalid argument... выглядит не очень странно для mkdir(), так как это прямое подозрение, что имя в качестве аргумента является динамическим и исходит из процесса обработки картинки, с которой косяк с самого начала. Так что код в студию.

Comment: http://codepaste.ru/14385/
http://codepaste.ru/14386/

А вот вызов функции
http://codepaste.ru/14387/

Comment: `$path_to_image_directory` не определен поди или пустой.

Comment: эта переменная определена

Comment: @Алексей Скляр, значит путь не верно указан.